# Authentication with email and password not completely working in Firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

First of all, I would like to state that I am relatively new to Firebase. I am wondering whether if one makes a successful `POST` for **sign in** to a Realtime Database, and I confirmed that the user is authenticated via the **Firebase Console**, is the user automatically authenticated on the website?

There's a problem that I came across with my website where the user cannot access the `/recipes` path even after the user logged in.

First of all, my Firebase security looks like this. It's relatively simple.

```json
{
  "rules": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  ".write": "auth != null"
 }
}
```

Now my login method looks like this. Keep in mind, I am using the Angular framework, but I will explain the simple built in Angular methods

```js
// basically, this will announce application-wide that a new user signed in.
user = new Subject<User>()

login(email: string, password: string) {
// sending to the Firebase signin endpoint
        return this.http.post<AuthResponseData>('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[MyAPIkey]', {
            email: email,
            password: password,
            returnSecureToken: true
        }).pipe(tap(resData => {
            this.handleAuthentication(resData.email, resData.localId, resData.idToken)
        }))
// pipe is a method that allows tap to exist. Tap is how we can call a function when the POST is successful WITHOUT changing the output


private handleAuthentication(email: string, id: string, tokenId: string) {
        let now = new Date().getTime() / 1000
        let user = new User(email, id, tokenId, (3600 * now))
// the first 2 lines work fine, but I have a feeling the error might be from the next 2 lines.
        user.token
        this.user.next(user)
    }
```

My User Model looks like this:

```
export class User {
    constructor(
        public email: string, 
        public id: string, 
        private _token: string, 
        private _tokenExpirationDate: number) {

        }

    get token() {
        if (!this._tokenExpirationDate || new Date().getTime() > this._tokenExpirationDate) {
            return null
        }
        else {
// this console.log works perfectly, but I am not sure if this code has anything to do with the problem. Do we even need to return the token like what's the purpose of returning it?
            console.log("hello this is returned!")
            return this._token
            
        }
    }
}
```

Now, since I am not allowed to go to `/recipes` (which is where we fetch the data from the Realtime database), I would assume that `auth` is `null` which is why we can't access the data. Now, what do I need to add or edit with my code in order for it to actually be authenticated and then I access `/recipes`. I am also trying to up my skill in reading documentation so if you could provide quotes from official documentation, that would be great. If you can't do that, just answering this question will be more than enough. :)

Comment: I don't see any code that accesses the Realtime Database at first glance. Did you forget to share that?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Isn't the `POST` request enough? I called `login` (which sends a request to the sign in with email & password REST API) in a different Angular component and I `subscribed` to it and `console.log` the response object. I got the response object but for some reason I am still getting a `401 Unauthorized access` when I try to access `/recipes`

Comment: That calls `identitytoolkit.googleapis.com`, which is not accessing the Realtime Database. For the RTDB REST API, see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start. But given that you are just getting started, I recommend using the Firebase SDKs for your platform, rather than the REST APIs.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Well, Angular applications are Single Page Applications, and correct me if I am wrong but I may have to use the REST API in order for my Single Page Application to work. Either way, I will definitely check out the link.

Comment: Angular apps can use the Firebase [JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) and/or the [AngularFire libraries](https://github.com/angular/angularfire). No need to use the REST API.